# Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable, and that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there are positive numbers $c_{n}$ and $\delta_{n}$ such that $|g(x)| \leq c_{n}|x|^n$ if $|x|<\delta_{n}$. Prove that for each natural number $n$, $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$.

My attempt using induction is as follows:

Base case ($n = 1$): By supposition there are $c_{1} >0$ and $\delta_{1} >0$ such that $|g(x)| \leq 
 c_{1}|x|$ if $|x|<\delta_{1}$. Setting $x = 0$ yields that $|g(0)| \leq c_{1}|0| = 0$ and therefore $g(0) = 0$

Fix $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $g^{(k)}(0) = 0$. This is the point where I get stuck. I have tried applying the Lagrange Remainder Theorem at this point, but have been unsuccessful. I understand this is not much to work with, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo: You should start the base case from $0$. $g^{(1)}$ is the first derivative of $g$: $g'$ not $g$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show recursively that the coefficients of the Taylor serie   ( or the limited development)  are zero by dividing by $x^n$ and computing the limit.

Comment: Could you be any more specific, please?

Comment: The first case $f(x)= a_1x +a_2x+O(x^2)$, if $x<\delta_2$, $|a_1x+a_2x^2+ O(x^2)|\leq c_2 |x|^2$, this implies that $|{{a_1}\over x}+{{O(x^2)}\over {x^2}}|\leq c_2$ implies $a_1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If the claim is false, then let $k$ be the least natural number such that $g^{(k)}(0)\ne 0.$ Then in a suitable neighborhood of zero, one has $g(x)=x^k\left(a_k+a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+\cdots +\right)$ so $|g(x)|=|x^k||a_k+a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+\cdots +|\le c_k|x^k|.$ It follows that $\left|\frac{g(x)}{x^k}\right|\le c_k.$ Now, $g$ is bounded on $(-\delta_k,\delta_k)$, so letting $x\to 0$, we obtain a contradiction.